# Getting DataTable row clicked on with context menu

Tags: javascript, datatables, contextmenu

I would like to add a context menu to each of my DataTable rows.

I want to get the row that was clicked on and then some way to identify it (I suppose the first cell value which contains the primary key would work) and then send an AJAX request containing the PK and option clicked.

I have figured out how to get the row by using "tr" as a selector, but how can I get the 1st cell's value (which contains the primary key). This prints out all of the cells:

```js
$(function(){
    $.contextMenu({
        selector: 'td', 
        trigger: 'right',
        callback: function(key, options) {
            var  m = $(options.$trigger).text();
            window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m);
        },
        items: {
            "delete": {name: "Delete", icon: "delete"},
    }); 
});
```

Also, is this the best way to do this? I plan to have ~10 options in the context menu that interact with the rows. I am using Django as the backend.

Answer (score 3):

Always use the API when you want to interact with DT. If you have an instance

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {..} )
```

then retrieve the current row by passing `options.$trigger` which holds the `<tr>` node :

```
$.contextMenu({
  selector: 'tr', 
  trigger: 'right',
  callback: function(key, options) {
    var row = table.row(options.$trigger)
    switch (key) {
      case 'delete' :
        row.remove().draw()
        break;
      case ...
    } 
  },
  items: {
    'delete': { name: 'Delete', icon: 'delete' },
    ...
  }
})
```

> but how can I get the 1st cell's value (which contains the primary
>   key).

```
row.data()[0]
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/z2q5scgr/**